# finding maximum depth of random forest given the number of features

Tags: machine-learning, random-forest

How do we find maximum depth of Random Forest if we know the number of features ?

This is needed for regularizing random forest classifier.

Comment: Have a look at [this](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/174668/relation-between-decision-tree-depth-and-number-of-attributes/174901#174901) _very_ similar question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The maximum depth of a forest is a parameter which you set yourself. If you're asking how do you find the optimal depth of a tree given a set of features then this is through cross-validation. For example, create 5 rf's with 5 different tree depths and see which one performs the best on the validation set.